# Combine 2 lists and output in a new list with indexes changed

Tags: apex, list, map, indexing

I have a map as below:

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> iMap = new Map<Integer, List<String>>{
    1 => new List<String>{'a','b','c'},
    2 => new List<String>{'d','e','f'}        
};
```

What I am trying is to combine the 2 list values for above map which if done as below outputs as `(a,b,c,d,e,f)`

```
List<String> combinedList = new List<String>();
combinedList.addAll(iMap.get(1));
combinedList.addAll(iMap.get(2));
```

but I am looking to out put above list as `(a,d,b,e,c,f)` {one value from each key of the map}

I tried to do as shown below which didnt work and obviously doing same as above. Looking for suggestions.

```
Integer totalCount = combinedList.size();
List<String> returnList = new String[totalCount];

for(Integer i = 0; i < totalCount; i++){
    /*1*/if(math.mod(i+1, 2) != 0) returnList.set(i, combinedList.get(i));
    /*2*/else returnList.set(i, combinedList.get(i));
}

system.debug(returnList);
```

*** Map defined above will have lists of equal size (though solution for unequal size will be more ideal for me)

Comment: And what if the lists are not of the same size?

Comment: thats another tricky thing.. some times, ya as u said map can contain lists of unequal sizes

Comment: Outside of guessing, this question is not answerable without knowing your requirements...please **[edit]** your post to clarify what needs to happen in this edge case.

Comment: I can make the 2 lists in the map equal size.. edited the question to reflect same

Comment: @sf_user So your function will only ever deal with lists of the same size?

Comment: as edited in my question, I can make the lists as equal sizes. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say you should take these steps:

1. Get the maximum length of all lists.
2. Generate a sorted list of map keys.
3. Iterate through integer indices up to this maximum.
4. Iterate through your ordered keys and pull the value if your index is valid.

Roughly:

```
public static List<String> interleave(Map<Integer, List<String>> input)
{
    List<String> output = new List<String>();

    // Step 1
    Integer maxSize = 0;
    for (List<String> value : input.values())
    {
        if (value.size() > maxSize)
        {
            maxSize = value.size();
        }
    }

    // Step 2
    List<Integer> sortedKeys = new List<Integer>(input.keySet());
    sortedKeys.sort();

    for (Integer i = 0; i < maxSize; i++)
    { // Step 3
        for (Integer key : sortedKeys)
        { // Step 4
            List<String> value = input.get(key);
            if (value.size() > i)
            {
                output.add(value[i]);
            }
        }
    }
    return output;
}
```

---

And a couple input/output checks:

**Input**

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> input = new Map<Integer, List<String>>{
    1 => new List<String>{'a','b','c'},
    2 => new List<String>{'d','e','f'}
};
system.debug(interleave(input));
```

**Output**

> (a, d, b, e, c, f)

**Input**

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> input = new Map<Integer, List<String>>{
    1 => new List<String>{'a','b','c'},
    2 => new List<String>{'w', 'x','y','z'},
    4 => new List<String>{'n', 'o'}
};
system.debug(interleave(input));
```

**Output**

> (a, w, n, b, x, o, c, y, z)

Answer (score 1):

If you lists are of equal size following should do a job

```
Map<Integer, List<String>> iMap = new Map<Integer, List<String>>{
    1 => new List<String>{'a','b','c'},
    2 => new List<String>{'d','e','f'}        
};


List<String> returnList = new List<String> ();


List<String> List1=iMap.get(1);
List<String> List2=iMap.get(2);

Integer totalCount = List1.size();

if (totalCount == List2.size())
{
    for(Integer i = 0; i < totalCount; i++){
        returnList.add(List1.get(i));
        returnList.add(List2.get(i));
    }

    system.debug(returnList);
}
else
{
    //thow exception
    //or return null
}
```